# Elasticsearch NEST V2 Completion Context Mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, nest

I have functionality needed to provide an autocomplete which only returns documents of a certain type in my index.

I have the auto complete suggestor working without a Context applied. But when I try and map the context, it fails.

Here is the mapping that I have.

```c#
.Map<MyType>(l => l
.Properties(p => p
    .Boolean(b => b
        .Name(n => n.IsArchived)
    )
    .String(s => s
        .Name(n => n.Type)
        .Index(FieldIndexOption.No)
    )
    .AutoMap()
    .Completion(c => c
        .Name(n => n.Suggest)
        .Payloads(false)
        .Context(context => context
            .Category("type", cat => cat
                .Field(field => field.Type)
                .Default(new string[] { "defaultType" })
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong as there are not any errors in intellisense or build.

Comment: what version of NEST 2.x? And what version of Elasticsearch are you running against?

Comment: NEST 2.1.0 and Elasticsearch 2.3.0

Answer (score 1):

[The Context Suggester mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/suggester-context.html) is not correct and won't compile as is; `AutoMap()` is not a method on `PropertiesDescriptor<T>`, but is a method on `PutMappingDescriptor<T>`. Take a look at [the completion suggester mapping that is used as part of the integration tests](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/2.x/src/Tests/Framework/Integration/Bootstrappers/Seeder.cs#L168-L176). It should look like the following

```
public class MyType
{
    public bool IsArchived { get; set;}

    public string Type { get; set;}

    public  CompletionField<object> Suggest { get; set;}
}

client.Map<MyType>(l => l
    .AutoMap()
    .Properties(p => p
        .Boolean(b => b
            .Name(n => n.IsArchived)
        )
        .String(s => s
            .Name(n => n.Type)
            .Index(FieldIndexOption.No)
        )

        .Completion(c => c
            .Name(n => n.Suggest)
            .Context(context => context
                .Category("type", cat => cat
                    .Field(field => field.Type)
                    .Default("defaultType")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which results in the following mapping

```
{
  "properties": {
    "isArchived": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "no"
    },
    "suggest": {
      "type": "completion",
      "context": {
        "type": {
          "type": "category",
          "path": "type",
          "default": [
            "defaultType"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cheers. In my example I did not mention I was trying to map with across multiple types. I was trying to set different default values for each type, which is where it was failing. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#field-conflicts